# UEFI Boot Options not on Windows' boot partition get wiped?

Tags: boot, partitioning, dualboot

I'm not sure why, but it seems like any boot options on my SSD that I add that isn't part of Windows' boot partition seem to be reverted every time I reboot my system.

I tried making a separate partition for my ArchLinux installation, however when adding that partition to the UEFI boot thingy (via efibootmgr or EasyUEFI), it gets removed when I reboot. But when I install GRUB to Windows' partition and try doing the same thing but with that partition instead, it works just fine.

I am using a `1.0 / Z370-A PRO (MS-7B48)` motherboard, an `i5-8400` CPU, and `GTX 1050 Ti` graphics card. The SSD in question is an `ATA ADATA SU650`

Comment: Only one ESP (EFI System Partition) is reuired **and recommended**. It's not a Windows partition, it's for any and all OSes in a multi-boot scenario. And although you can have more (again, not recommended), only one per drive is the rule.

Comment: Cool thank you. I didn't know this.